# How do I query more information of an array in a json file using mongodb?

Tags: arrays, json, database, mongodb, nosql

```
{
"userid": 1,
"following": [2, 3],
"salary": 1000,
"age": 19
},
{
"userid": 2,
"following": [],
"salary": 2000,
"age": 25
},
{
"userid": 3,
"following": [2],
"salary": 1500,
"age": 20
},
```

"following" shows the userid of the people the user follows.
I would like to have an output query showing the userid and the salary of those that he follows only (no need age and the user's salary). I saw that $lookup() could be used but I am unsure of using it.

My desired output is shown below, may I know if it is possible? I am also open to any other outputs. Thank you in advance!

```
{
"userid": 1,
"following": [{2, 2000}, {3, 1500}]
},
{
"userid": 2,
"following": []
},
{
"userid": 3,
"following": [{2, 2000}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) to join the collection to itself, then use [`project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to exclude unwanted fields like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$following",
      connectFromField: "following",
      connectToField: "userid",
      as: "following",
      maxDepth: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "userid": 1,
      "following.salary": 1,
      "following.userid": 1
    }
  }
])
```

The output is not the same as you wanted, but as you said you are open to all suggestions I posted:

```
[
  {
    "following": [
      {
        "salary": 2000,
        "userid": 2
      },
      {
        "salary": 1500,
        "userid": 3
      }
    ],
    "userid": 1
  },
  {
    "following": [],
    "userid": 2
  },
  {
    "following": [
      {
        "salary": 2000,
        "userid": 2
      }
    ],
    "userid": 3
  }
]
```

Playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/WnF1vRY5Avr